# Use Neo4j for an instant messaging webApp

Tags: neo4j, instant-messaging

How does a Graph DataBase like Neo4j perform on an instant messaging webApp ?
Any information on that matter would be really appreciated :) !

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us more about your app's domain entities and how they are supposed to interact? Answers to such a broad question can be broad as well :)

Comment: Fair enough :). In the webApp project, the data model is composed of multiple "object" like people, topic, chats ... they're all linked together. "Social Network" are big words to describe it, but it's kind of related to it.
So using a relational DataBase isn't in my opinion a good choice, using a document orient isn't either... Graph DB could be a solution, but I was wondering if, for the instant messaging part, Graph DataBase would be a "good choice", or I should combined Graph DB with another kind of DataBase.

Answer (score -1):

NoSql databases like Neo4j are great when used with transaction databases, where loads of transactions occur. They are also superior to relational databases when relationships between Nodes are constantly increasing. For a system like an instant messaging app you can setup the relationships between users, where they 'know' each other. Or you can have a image node and create a relationship between the image and the user. With this connection/relationship the system will be able to supply related node properties much faster because it has direct links, compared to a relational database with its table Joins.